# I resolved all review requests. Why does my PR in Github still say "1 change requested"?

Tags: github, review

In my PR, I resolved all review requests, but, at the bottom, it gives my reviewer's name and says "1 change requested." I unhid each resolved request looking for further comment from my reviewer, but I can't find any.[1 change requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2h2v.png)

I searched for any unresolved requested changes, but didn't find any. I expect to find 1.

Comment: That stays there until the reviewer reviews the PR again and approves it. You can [re-request a review](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/about-pull-request-reviews#re-requesting-a-review) so the reviewer gets a notification.